# MS SQL Connection: Android Studio never connects vs Eclipse IDE does

Tags: java, android, sql-server, eclipse, android-studio

I am creating a program for a local organization to take inventory. App connects to SQL Server via MSSQL 8.2 connector. App on phone should allow for receiving and sending item information. I have a static class to connect to the database, that handles the connection. In Eclipse, I am able to successfully connect and query the database. In Android studio, I get errors on every attempt to connect.

-Server is hosted on same pc.

-Ports have been configured, repeatedly. Currently have inbound and outbound rules for TCP and UDP fully open. Dynamic ports are on for SQL server. Services for SQL server have been restarted dozens of times. 1433 has been enabled and toggled off, but are currently blank.

-Attempted to connect by IP address, host cannot be resolved

-Permissions edited to allow login access to modify the database

-Integrated security and TLS security tried at different times, both failed.

List of errors:

- Connection to  the host BLACK-G, "xxxxx" port 1433, has failed.
  TCP/IP connection to the host failed, unable to resolve host.
- Connection to the host named BLACK-G instance sqlexpress failed,No
  address associated with hostname, open up UDP traffic to port 1434
  Unknown host exception. Unable to resolve host BLACK-G
- Connection Refused
- Failed to connect
- Connection to the host 192.168.1.219 has failed. Failed to connect to
  192.168.1.219 (port 1433) from 192.168.1.87(port 33654) after 2478ms Verify connection properties.

Here is the code

```
package com.example.ccupboard_1;

import android.os.Build;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


 public class DatabaseJAVA  {

   //  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)//public static void main(String[] args) {
    public static String Connect() {

        // Create a variable for the connection string.
      
         String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://BLACK-G\\SQLEXPRESS;user=ay7;password=343434;databaseName=ayTestDatabase2;" ;

        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        
   

        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
             Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) {

            // Create and execute a SELECT SQL statement.
            String selectSql = "SELECT Fname, Lname from dbo.Customers";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(selectSql);

            // Print results from select statement
            while (resultSet.next()) {

                result += (resultSet.getString("Fname") + " " + resultSet.getString("Lname")+"\n");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            result = e + "";
        }
        return result;
    }
    }
```

Snippet from main activity that calls connect method:

```
case R.id.buttonSignOut: { //used to test connection currently, simply attempts to connect and //returns the value to a textview on the page

                Thread thread = new Thread() {

                    public void run() {

                        textviewLowItemAlert.setText(DatabaseJAVA.Connect());

                    }

                };

                thread.start();

                break;
```

What would be the next step in resolving this issue? It works in Eclipse, but not in studio. I've tried more than a dozen different connection Strings, and most of them threw the same errors. Does my server not allow access to Android Studio? Most of the errors seem to be Android studio being incapable of locating it on the server.

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez Alright, I gave your connection a try.  I increased the time to timeout, and started it. This time, I got Network Error IOException, EHOSTUNREACH(No route to host) I am assuming that there is something wrong network wise, and will play with that for a while.

Comment: @JoaquinAlvarez Router changed my ip address from .218 to .219. I changed this in the string, then tried again. This time, it said it could not locate the instance of BlackPC\SQLEXPRESS. I shortened it to SQLEXPRESS, and it said DB server closed connection. Still playing with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet from a working app of mine where I can connect succesfully to a local ms sql.

In a config file I set the connection info.

```
  public static String dbUser = "user";
  public static String dbPassword = "password";
  public final static String sqlString = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://ip:port//INSTANCENAME";
```

Then I start the connection like this.

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
 DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Config.sqlString, Config.dbUser, Config.dbPassword);       // Connect to database
        if (connection == null) {
            ConnectionResult = "Verify Internet Connection";
            Toast.makeText(activity, ConnectionResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Finally just do the query and close the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, was finally able to figure it out, with the JDBC-JTDS connector mentioned by JoaquinAlvarez.
Here's what happened:

-Used the connection info he provided, with my IP address, and a higher timeout

-Network Error IOException, EHOSTUNREACH(No route to host),

-Router changed my IP address, so had to fix that

-After that, I used my PCNAME\SQLEXPRESS for the the for the instance

-It returned Instance Unreachable, so I changed to SQLEXPRESS alone

-Then it returned DB Closed connection

-I looked at Windows Event Viewer, and it said:
"Encryption is required to connect to this server but the client library does not support encryption; the connection has been closed. Please upgrade your client library."

-I checked the SQL server in SQL SERVER Configuration Manager... Force Encryption was turned on.

-Tried again, and the JTDS connector finally connected to the Database and I was able to do things. No help with the MSSQL one yet though.
Thank you Mr. Alvarez!